# Syntax error: "(" unexpected assigning an array in bash

Tags: bash

Within a bash script, I'm trying to pull all files with an extension '.jstd' into an array, loop over that array and carry out some action.

My script is failing to copy the path of each script into the array.

I have the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
file_list=($(find '/var/www' -type f -name "*.jstd"))
for i in "${file_list[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done

echo $file_list
unset IFS
```

The line **file_list=($(find '/var/www' -type f -name "*.jstd"))** works fine in the terminal, but fails in the script with:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've googled, but failed.  All ideas gratefully received.

edit: In case it helps in reproduction or clues, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, with GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Don't do this. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for reasons why. Do this correctly http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . Also [`mapfile`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) might be useful here for bash 4+.

Comment: That error indicates that you aren't invoking your script with bash. Are you perhaps running `sh yourscript`? If so, the manual use of `sh` will override the `#!/bin/bash` shebang. (Also, allow me to strongly echo the advice given by @EtanReisner; reading from `find` into an array in this manner is a very lossy process).

Comment: ...also, `echo $file_list` doesn't make sense for an array. `printf '%q\n' "${file_list[@]}"` would make sense, sure, but as it is your code only prints the *first* array entry, and that after string-splitting and glob-expanding it (since you don't quote correctly).

Comment: Yes, I was running through sh!  Excellent spot and newbie error.  Cheers.  If you want to make that an answer, I can accept.  Reap the rewards of your knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely the error you would get if your shell were `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu, not bash:

```
$ dash -c 'foo=( bar )'
dash: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

If you're running your script with `sh yourscript` -- don't. You **must** invoke bash scripts with bash.

---

That being given, though -- the better way to read a file list from `find` would be:

```
file_list=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  file_list+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find '/var/www' -type f -name "*.jstd" -print0)
```

...the above approach working correctly with filenames containing spaces, newlines, glob characters, and other corner cases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `+=`, I always find out something new about bash :)

Comment: BTW, my `read` command was actually slightly wrong -- wasn't clearing IFS, so whitespace on the end of filenames would be silently deleted. That's fixed now.